# The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, reference, report, reporting

I simply get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

after adding this to my code:

```
protected global::Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer ReportViewer1;
```

I've seen some solutions saying I must add some assemblies. but none of them worked. 
here is an example:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I did it by right-clicking on **References** folder in my project and then selecting **Add Reference**. and then adding **Assemblies > Extensions > Microsoft.ReportViewer** to the references.

Comment: I searched for Microsoft.ReportViewer in Extensions, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 37):

In my case I needed to actually install Microsoft Report Viewer on the troublesome machine.

- <strike>[Report Viewer 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6442) (version=10)</strike>
- [Report Viewer 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=27231) (version=10)
- [Report Viewer 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35747) (version=11)
- [Report Viewer 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496)

Of course, other ones are available, it can be worked out which from the `Version=` on the dll which one is needed. In my case I needed version 11 (the 2012 one).

Answer (score 17):

All these installs didn't work for me at all. What worked for me inside Visual Studio 2015 is installing the following two packages (I only needed these two) from NuGet (menu Project > Manage NuGet Packages):

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.VS2010
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.VS2010

The references were added to current project automatically.

Comment: This sorted it for me when I had this issue with VSTS online

Comment: Same problem for me. After adding my reports project to my VS2017 solution I deleted VS2015 not realizing this would break my code. Adding the VS2015 versions of the ReportViewer dlls via nuget fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Install ReportViewer from Nuget Package Manager

Comment: When I try to do this, I am facing numbers library named ReportViewer. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Just install [SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx). Then you need to remove the broken reference and re-add it from Assemblies > Extensions.

Answer (score 1):

import from :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

Comment: You can make this answer better by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32881033/edit) to explain how does it work.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when attempting to install a newer version of the SQL Server Reporting Services Report Viewer Control than the current target version of .NET.

Installing an earlier version of the nuget resolved this e.g. instead of version 15, installing version 14 worked

[Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms#versions-body-tab)