# The type or namespace name 'WebForms' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Reporting' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, web-services, reporting-services, webforms

I am trying to create a web service that will run an SSRS report and save it to a pdf. To do so, I am using VS 2013. When I try to build the solution I get  a number of errors including the following:

> The type or namespace name 'WebForms' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Reporting' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I checked my references, and I have already added the reference for Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms (v 10.0.0.0). Additionally, on top of the file that this error references, I have the following using statement:

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
```

Is there anything else I could be missing?

Thanks

Edit: my issue was that I was using a version of .NET that was too old.

Comment: .net version is one thought, the 64/32 bitness is also a normal gotcha.

Comment: The project currently has a target framework of .NET 2.0 - its pretty old. It was originally meant to run crystal reports, and I have to update it to run SSRS reports

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814563/the-type-or-namespace-name-reporting-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsof)

Comment: I flagged this a  dupe, as when I went to look for solutions for you, I found one here.

Comment: Thanks. To fix this, I had to update my solution to have a higher target framework.

Comment: My pleasure, I love this sh*t :-)