# Visual Studio 2017 - Unable to add "ReportViewer" to "Windows Form"

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.0, reportviewer

I know this question is exactly the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814563/the-type-or-namespace-name-reporting-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsof) but even after following it's solution i am still stuck up with this error

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

### Things i did to install Report Viewer

I followed the below link to install the report viewer

[Download and Install Report Viewer For Visual Studio 2017 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyqQ5UcA78k)
 (this link shows how to install it from **NuGet Manager** and **Extensions and update**)

and i was able to make a **Report** as well as add **Report Viewer** to my **Windows Form**
but i am getting the above mentioned error on building the program

### Solutions i have tried

1. I tried re-adding the reference by right-clicking on **References** folder in my project and then selecting **Add Reference**. and then adding **Assemblies** > **Extensions** > **Microsoft.ReportViewer** to the references.
2. I tried unloading the project and changing it's **.csproj** file and manually mention the version
   [image]
3. Also **cleaned the whole solution** and manually removed any other remaining files in the output directory and rebuilding it.

### BUT

when i try to see the designer of the form in which **ReportViewer** has been inserted then the **Tooltip** says that it is recognizing the namespace
[image]

Now, I am left with no solutions now. Any piece of advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use NuGet Package for install Reporting Service on your Winform application.

I use this NuGet and it's working fine for me.

[Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/)

Comment: If you see the installation link it used NugetManager to install the Report Viewer

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to change my .Net Framework from **4.0 Client Framework** to **4.0**. I guess it needs full features of that framework rather than the client version for it.