# "The type or namespace Reporting does not exist" in WinForms project

Tags: c#, winforms, report, reporting, viewer

The type or namespace reporting does not exist in the namespace microsoft in windows Form.
Following code are to be shown when I click on the error

'''public Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer reportViewer1;'''

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.v11` or some other nuget

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814563/the-type-or-namespace-name-reporting-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsof)

Comment: [Integrate Reporting Services Using the Report Viewer Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started)

Comment: I have Install Microsoft.reporting.winforms but still got the error

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by right-clicking on references in Solution Explorer and adding Microsoft.ReportViewer reference from Extensions in Assemblies.

**References > Add Reference > Assemblies > Extensions > Microsoft.ReportViewer**

Hope it works.